# C# WPF Tooltips not showing on child grid

Tags: wpf, tooltip

For some reason the tooltips won't show in my child grid.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    Width="300px"
    Height="250px"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="MainGrid Tooltip">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.25*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        ToolTip="mygrid tooltip 2">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="15"
                Source="<<INSERT IMAGE FILE LOCATION HERE>>" 
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Child Grid Tooltip 1"/>
        <TextBlock Width="80"
                Text="Random Text 2"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Child Grid Tooltip 2"/>
        <TextBlock Width="80" 
                Text="Random Text 3"
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="Child Grid Tooltip 3"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

I keep getting the "mygrid tooltip 2" being displayed, even though I have overridden the tooltip for it's children - it won't show.

I have lessened the complexity from having control templates in resource dictionaries until I am now only left with this above, and still nothing.

any ideas will be greatly appreciated, also perhaps links where I can read up about it.  my WPF book and msdn isn't producing anything substancial at the moment.

thanks,

Comment: I have tried your code and i didn't find any problems.The tooltips are showing as intended.The Image and text controls are showing their own respective tooltips

Comment: I've rechecked the source file and found I forgot to mention that the source xaml starts as a "ResourceDictionary", and the page itself is a "DataTemplate"

not sure if that should matter, clearly it does though.

The backend framework is designed to use these datatemplates and generate the required pages, which works perfectly except for the child child grid.

<ResourceDictionary>
 <DataTemplate>
  <Grid>
   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid tooltip=working>
     <Grid Tooltip=not working>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Isak, thanks, your `Background="Transparent"` assisted in my final solution.

I ultimately threw away the Grid with defined rows / columns, and resorted to a Grid with nested StackPanels.

Previously the Grid.Rows were being populated by ContentControls, I replaced this with local Stackpanels containing the information I needed to display and that seemed to have solved it, but only after I added the "Transparent" tag to the stackpanels and also a

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

on an image in the parent grid which serves as a background image.

Herewith an example of my current solution, the second part which replaces the code seen in my original post.

First, the basic source file layout before getting to the code in question looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="...
  <DataTemplate DataType="...
    <Grid Style="...
      <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

       <Grid Name="LeftColumn" Grid.Column="0">
         <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextHeader}"
                    Text="Review 10 Patients"/>

         <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Stretch="None"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Source="((INSERT IMAGE HERE))" Margin="0,-2,0,10"/>
```

And then my solution grid as follows [replaces initial post code]:

```
       <StackPanel>

         <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image Style="{StaticResource InfoImage}" Margin="3">
             <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
               <ToolTip Width="200" Style="{StaticResource ToolTip}"
                        Content="ToolTip 1"/>
             </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
           </Image>

           <TextBlock Width="140" Style="{StaticResource Text_SelfTitle}"
                      Text="Text Field 1"/>
           <TextBlock Width="145" Style="{StaticResource Text_SelfQuestions}"
                      Text="Text Field 2"/>
         </StackPanel>

         <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal">
            ((... similar as above...))
         </StackPanel>

         <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal">
            ((... similar as above...))
         </StackPanel>

       </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Hope this helps somebody else should you experience something similar.

Answer (score 14):

In order for something in WPF to be able to display a tooltip, it has to be visible to  hit testing.

In the case of panels, this is done by setting the background color to something besides `null` (which is the default for all panels). If you want your panels to be invisible but still be eligible for hit testing, you can use `Transparent` as the background color.

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" ToolTip="This Will Be Shown">
    <!-- other stuff -->
</Grid>

<Grid ToolTip="This Will NOT Be Shown">
    <!-- other stuff -->
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Isak, I've tried the background method you proposed above without success, I even changed it to red which shows the exact grid row, but still no tooltip. sigh.  I've left a comment above for biju with some extra details, maybe that influences it?