# wpf grid tooltip not showing

Tags: wpf, image

I have an image, and I want to show different tool tip when hover over the image section
and the image has 4 sections

I have tried this so far:

```
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition   ToolTip="11" />
            <ColumnDefinition  ToolTip="2" />
            <ColumnDefinition  ToolTip="3" />
            <ColumnDefinition  ToolTip="4" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Name="SupportToolBlocks" Height="42" Width="168"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a "layer" on top of the Image, and in each of the 4 columns in the layer, add a transparent border (set its background as "Transparent" so it becomes visible to hit testing, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106563/815938) for more details). Like this

```
<Grid Height="42" Width="168">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="SupportToolBlocks" Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="layer">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" ToolTip="A"/>
        <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="B"/>
        <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="C"/>
        <Border Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="3" ToolTip="D"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```